# Example of a "abrupt function"

Tags: numerical-methods, spline, lagrange-interpolation, interpolation-theory, programming

I need example of a simple function to show that cubic spline gives better result than Lagrange's interpolation in case of some special functions.
Thank you

Comment: Please define "better result". And please share your own efforts on this problem.

Comment: By better I mean better approximation at the interpolating point

Comment: Please share your own efforts on this problem, including a few numeric examples and any other relevant piece of information.

Comment: I tried with sin(1 /x) but it didn't work..I need some example which is already tested

Comment: I have written a program on this. I have to demonstrate the speciality of cubic spline... Most of the cases Lagrange's interpolation gives better approximation... Except for a few..I want to know at least one member from that "few" where cubic spline wins

Comment: Take samples from an even function that has an asymptote such as y=1/(1+x^2) with for example not equally spread points like $(-4,1/17)(-3,1/10),(3,1/10)(4,1/17)$ that are likely to produce bumps in Lagrange interpolation.